# <s:checkboxlist> error: have seen it around 100 times now

Tags: jsp, struts2, checkboxlist

I am aware that similar type of question has been asked on the site. But the answers submitted to these haven't satisfied my problem yet.So here's my error:

[image]

The initial page of my project:
**checkBoxList.jsp**

```
<%@ taglib prefix="s" uri="/struts-tags" %>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<s:form action="resultAction">
<h4>
<s:checkboxlist label="What's your favor color" list="colors" 
   name="yourcolor" value="defaultColor" />
</h4> 

<s:submit value="submit" name="submit" />
</s:form>
</body>
</html>
```

My result page:
**result.jsp**

```
<%@ taglib prefix="s" uri="/struts-tags" %>
<html>

<body>
<h1>Struts 2 multiple check boxes example</h1>

<h4>
Favor colors : <s:property value="yourColor"/>
</h4> 

</body>
</html>
```

My Action page:
**CheckBoxListAction.java**

```
package com.vishal.common.action;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import com.opensymphony.xwork2.ActionSupport;

public class CheckBoxListAction extends ActionSupport{

private List<String> colors;

private String yourcolor;

public String getYourColor() {
    return yourcolor;
}

public void setYourColor(String yourColor) {
    this.yourcolor = yourColor;
}

public CheckBoxListAction(){
    colors = new ArrayList<String>();
    colors.add("red");
    colors.add("yellow");
    colors.add("blue");
    colors.add("green");
}

public String[] getDefaultColor(){
    return new String [] {"red", "green"};
}

public List<String> getColors() {
    return colors;
}

public void setColors(List<String> colors) {
    this.colors = colors;
}

public String execute() {
    return SUCCESS;
}

public String display() {
    return NONE;
}
```

}

And my struts.xml page:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE struts PUBLIC
"-//Apache Software Foundation//DTD Struts Configuration 2.0//EN"
"http://struts.apache.org/dtds/struts-2.0.dtd">

<struts>
 <package name="default" namespace="/" extends="struts-default">

 <action name="checkBoxListAction" 
     class="com.vishal.common.action.CheckBoxListAction" method="display">
<result name="none">/checkBoxList.jsp</result>
 </action>

<action name="resultAction"     class="com.vishal.common.action.CheckBoxListAction">
  <result name="success">/result.jsp</result>
 </action>
</package>

</struts>
```

I don't think there may be a problem with my web.xml page. And as of my Folder Structure, here it is with project name:**StrutsCheckbox**

So please if anyone can help me with my error.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Regarding your error, you are trying to use the URL that has not a mapping in your xml configuration. You need `checkBoxListAction` to be invoked to initialize `colors` list. And this key should be available in the value stack. To invoke that action use this URL

```
http://localhost:8080/StrutsCheckbox/checkBoxListAction.action
```

Comment: No, you don't need it, it could be redirected. Like in [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17615096/573032) answer.

Answer (score 0):

1. Avoid using `NONE` (that is a specific predefined result to prevent from writing any output in the HttpResponse) as a result mapped to something. Either use a custom result, or just use `SUCCESS` (from `display()` or from `execute()`, it doesn't matter as long as it is mapped);
2. Move the list loading part from the constructor to your action method (and in future, to a `prepare()` method or similar);

Eg:

```java
public String execute(){
    colors = new ArrayList<String>();
    colors.add("red");
    colors.add("yellow");
    colors.add("blue");
    colors.add("green");

    return SUCCESS;
}
```

```xml
<!-- if no METHOD is specified, execute() is called --> 
<action name="checkBoxListAction" class="com.vishal.common.action.CheckBoxListAction">
    <!-- if no NAME of result is specified, SUCCESS is assumed -->
    <result>/checkBoxList.jsp</result>
</action>
```