# com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.DependencyException: com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.ContainerImpl$MissingDependencyException

Tags: xml, struts2, web.xml, servlet-filters

While deploying my war file I am getting the below exception:

```
SEVERE: Exception starting filter struts2
com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.ContainerImpl$MissingDependencyException: No mapping found for dependency [type=com.opensymphony.xwork2.ObjectFactory, name='default'] in public void com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.providers.XmlConfigurationProvider.setObjectFactory(com.opensymphony.xwork2.ObjectFactory). - Class: com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.ContainerImpl
File: ContainerImpl.java
Method: addInjectorsForMembers
Line: 144 - com/opensymphony/xwork2/inject/ContainerImpl.java:144:-1
        at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.init(Dispatcher.java:501)
        at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.InitOperations.initDispatcher(InitOperations.java:74)
        at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.init(StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.java:57)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.initFilter(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:279)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.getFilter(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:260)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.<init>(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:105)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.filterStart(StandardContext.java:4809)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5485)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:901)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:877)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:632)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:1073)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployWar.run(HostConfig.java:1857)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.DependencyException: com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.ContainerImpl$MissingDependencyException: No mapping found for dependency [type=com.opensymphony.xwork2.ObjectFactory, name='default'] in public void com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.providers.XmlConfigurationProvider.setObjectFactory(com.opensymphony.xwork2.ObjectFactory).
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.ContainerImpl.addInjectorsForMembers(ContainerImpl.java:144)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.ContainerImpl.addInjectorsForMethods(ContainerImpl.java:113)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.ContainerImpl.addInjectors(ContainerImpl.java:90)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.ContainerImpl.addInjectors(ContainerImpl.java:86)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.ContainerImpl$1.create(ContainerImpl.java:71)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.ContainerImpl$1.create(ContainerImpl.java:67)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.util.ReferenceCache$CallableCreate.call(ReferenceCache.java:150)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.util.ReferenceCache.internalCreate(ReferenceCache.java:76)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.util.ReferenceCache.get(ReferenceCache.java:116)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.ContainerImpl.inject(ContainerImpl.java:490)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.ContainerImpl$6.call(ContainerImpl.java:530)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.ContainerImpl$6.call(ContainerImpl.java:528)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.ContainerImpl.callInContext(ContainerImpl.java:584)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.ContainerImpl.inject(ContainerImpl.java:528)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.impl.DefaultConfiguration.reloadContainer(DefaultConfiguration.java:257)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.ConfigurationManager.getConfiguration(ConfigurationManager.java:67)
        at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.init_PreloadConfiguration(Dispatcher.java:445)
        at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.init(Dispatcher.java:489)
```

I have included the `struts-default.xml` in `init-param` in `web.xml` as suggested by some posts.

Still it is not working!!

Am I missing anything?

web.xml is similar as below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" 
   xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee 
   http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
   id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">

   <display-name>Struts 2</display-name>
   <welcome-file-list>
      <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
   </welcome-file-list>
   <filter>
      <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
      <filter-class>
         org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.FilterDispatcher
      </filter-class>
   </filter>

   <filter-mapping>
      <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
      <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
   </filter-mapping>
</web-app>
```

struts.xml is similar as below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE struts PUBLIC
   "-//Apache Software Foundation//DTD Struts Configuration 2.0//EN"
   "http://struts.apache.org/dtds/struts-2.0.dtd">
<struts>
<constant name="struts.devMode" value="true" />
   <package name="helloworld" extends="struts-default">

      <action name="hello" 
            class="com.tutorialspoint.struts2.HelloWorldAction" 
            method="execute">
            <result name="success">/HelloWorld.jsp</result>
      </action>
   </package>
</struts>
```

Comment: Show your `struts.xml` and `web.xml` files.

Comment: Hi Aleksandr, the content of these files are similar to what I have posted.

Comment: First fix the errors that Andrea pointed in his answer.

Answer (score 2):

1. Drop the **FilterDispatcher** that is deprecated, [and set the **new filter**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17103563/1654265).
2. Correct your DTDs: in **web.xml** you are mixing `2.5` with `3.0`. All `2.5` or all `3.0` (or all `2.4`, according to your application server specs). In **struts.xml**, it should be `2.3` unless you are using a really old version (and you should *not*).
3. Make sure you have included [**all** the required dependencies](http://struts.apache.org/maven/dependency-management.html), each one **only once**, and all with the **right** versions.

Comment: can you fix your links? They broke.

Comment: @ChrisAldrich Sure, done. Links are broken due to the migration of the Apache documentation of a couple of months ago. Before the docs were divided (and duplicated) per version, now they're unified.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same issue. I moved struts.xml file under resources folder so that it comes in the class path. I removed the init parameter for filter StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter which was pointing to the struts location. I am using below versions of libraries, along with maven.

```
<struts.version>2.3.16.3</struts.version>
<spring.version>4.1.2.RELEASE</spring.version>
<struts.spring.plugin>2.3.16.3</struts.spring.plugin>
```