# Why index page is giving 404 error in Struts 2

Tags: struts2, http-status-code-404, web.xml

If I am not including `web.xml` file then index file is opening properly but result page `HelloWorld.jsp` is giving 404 error, and when including `web.xml` index page is giving 404 error.

I have `index.jsp` file. `localhost:8080` is working correctly but after that it is giving error.

See here: 
[image]

---

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Exception starting filter struts2 - tried adding JAR's, but same result](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17096637/exception-starting-filter-struts2-tried-adding-jars-but-same-result)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the first case the index file is opened by the default servlet, that is available on the server.

In the second case you use `FilterDispatcher` that is deprecated.

You should upgrade Struts to the latest version and use

```xml
<filter-class>org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter</filter-class>
```

See how to write web application descriptor [web.xml](https://struts.apache.org/docs/webxml.html).

> ## Simple Example
>
> Configuring `web.xml` for the framework is a matter of adding a filter
>   and filter-mapping.
>
> `FilterDispatcher` Example (`web.xml`):
>
> ```xml
> <web-app id="WebApp_9" version="2.4"
>     xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee"
>     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
>     xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd">
>
>     <filter>
>         <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
>         <filter-class>org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter</filter-class>
>     </filter>
>
>     <filter-mapping>
>         <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
>         <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
>     </filter-mapping>
>
>     <!-- ... -->
>
> </web-app>
> ```